# Xcode 5 Auto Layout - Embedded Tables

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, autolayout

I have a `UIScrollView` with several `UITableView`s embedded in it.  I want to allow each table to expand its height as much as is needed to display all of its cells.  The scroll view's frame takes up the whole screen, so its `contentSize.height` need to expand to fit the biggest table (which I think is the default behavior, but I mention it just in case I'm incorrect).  Can this all be done on my storyboard?  Or if I will need to add code to do it, I found [this tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_iOS_6_Auto_Layout_Constraints_in_Code), but it's for iOS 6 - has any of the code for this constraint stuff changed for iOS 7?

Comment: I'm getting a little sick of asking this, but why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

If you know in advance how much room each table takes up you can do it purely in your storyboard, but because each UITableView is also a scrollview the default behavior of a UITableView is to fill the assigned size with content and scroll if there is overflow.

If you do not know the height of the tables at design time, you will need to set them at run time.  See [Autolayout a UIScrollView to fit content including subviews and grouped tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096021/autolayout-a-uiscrollview-to-fit-content-including-subviews-and-grouped-tables/16127931#16127931) for an example, the short answer is to add a height constraint to your table, drag it into your controller as an outlet, and then set the height when you know it.

Comment: Yeah I'm going to need the heights to be dynamic, so it looks like I'll have to do it in code, as I feared.  But thanks, I didn't know you could set up a constraint as an outlet.  So it looks like this will still be a little painful to set up (it was quite a headache before auto-layout as well), but at least I should just have to do it once and not have to worry about rotation or different screen sizes or anything.  Thanks, I'll up-vote and accept once I can confirm it works.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done both ways.Manually moving UI elements through code(mentioning locations) and overriding it in did rotate or through mentioning constraints in auto layout.

This link http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/auto-layout-updates-in-ios-7/ provides details of ios7 auto layout .

Comment: Yeah I saw this article when I was looking into this myself before I posted.  Unfortunately it doesn't have any info about how to set a height for resizing or how to do anything in code.  And the reason I want to get this working with auto layout is so I don't have to worry about things like rotation.