# Issues when using size classes

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout, xcode6, size-classes

I am using size classes in my app and I am trying to set a `UITableView` inside a `UIScrollView`, when I added a new constraints for both views I got this warning (2 views are horizontally ambiguous) .
My goal is to make both `UITableView` and `UIScrollView`  have the full size in all devices

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253937/views-are-horizontally-and-vertically-ambiguous-with-complex-layout). I think the 2nd answer will help you out.

Also, it sounds like you're only using a single size class for these views, Any/Any, but if you added constraints while in other size classes, they will only impact those size classes.  If you select the constraint and then go to the size inspector, it will tell you which size classes the constraint is installed on.